# Restoring database through SQL Management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a .bak file that I am restoring but SSMS gives an error that is

"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server running version 10.50.1600. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.1600. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)"

I have updated SSMS, now its version is 10.50.4000. But the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

You may not restore a backup of a higher version of SQL to a lower version of SQL.

Have a look at [sql server builds](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.gr/).

**`10.50.1600`** is **`SQL Server 2008 R2`** while **`10.00.1600`** is **`SQL Server 2008`**.

Updating SSMS is not going to work, as it is only a Client Tool, and not the Server itself.

You need to upgrade the Server engine in order for the upgrade to work.

To see this is true, you may open your newly upgraded SSMS and login to the server where you want to restore your backup. In the tree you will see the Server's version in a parenthesis next to the Server's name. You will notice that though you upgrader SSMS, the Server's version remains the same.

Comment: well this answer is useful but i have also upgraded my SQL Server in all this mess. now my SQL server is SQL server 2008 R2, but as you said in tree server's version is same as before i.e. 10.0.1600. The backup problem i solved by getting script file of the DB. but i need to solve this problem also for future. After upgrading my SQL server i am updating SSMS but that gives an error and can't update SSMS.

Comment: How did you upgrade? Did you upgrade or do you have two SQL Servers running?

Comment: i upgraded.. got setup from my friend

Comment: Go to Start->Run and enter services.msc and hit enter. Then scroll down to SQL Server. There you will see entries like `SQL Serve(SQL2008R2)`. Can you please list here all those entries?

Comment: SQL Active Directory Helper Service, SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER), SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS), SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER), SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS), SQL Server Browser, SQL Server VSS Writer

Comment: This dictates that you have two instances of SQL. You have an SQL Express instance and a non Express one. It is probable that you are still connected to the old instance and not to the updated one.

Comment: so now whats the remedy to my problem? which SQL should i remove and how (causing no problems to other programs)

Comment: You may leave both SQL instances. What you need to do is find out how to connect to SQL2008R2 instance and restore your DB there.